# How to round up to 3 decimal places in longtable latex?

Tags: tables, formatting, longtable

This is the table for which I want rounded up to 3 decimals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document
\begin{longtable}{llllll}
\caption{Summary Statistics }\\ 
Zone & North &  &  & Center &  \\
Variables & Mean & SD &  & Mean & SD \\
Outcome  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
X & 0.9333306 & 0.2494538 &  & 0.9359156 & 0.2449076 \\
Y & 0.1503803 & 0.3574512 &  & 0.1144668 & 0.318383 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Have a look at the `siunitx` package

Comment: Hi samcarter. I did try it but since I use longtable package, siunitx doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Package `siunitx` cooperates with longtable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{l*{5}{S[round-mode=places, round-precision=3, table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center]}}
\caption{Summary Statistics }\\
Zone & {North} & & & {Center} & \\
Variables & {Mean} & {SD} & & {Mean} & {SD} \\
Outcome & & & & & \\
X & 0.9333306 & 0.2494538 & & 0.9359156 & 0.2449076 \\
Y & 0.1503803 & 0.3574512 & & 0.1144668 & 0.318383 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]